# Saving to database from VB.NET WinForms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

How can you add data in a window form to a sql database in visual studio 2005?

I'm facing problems while saving.

```
Public Class Staff    
    Dim myconnection As SqlConnection
    Dim mycommand As SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
    Dim ra As Integer
    Private Sub cmdsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsave.Click
        myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=;database=medisam")
        myconnection.Open()
        mycommand = New SqlCommand("insert into staff([FirstName],[LastName],[Address],[DOB], [TelephoneNum], [DateJoinIn], [HighestQualifi], [AppointedAs], [Salary]) VALUES ('" & txtfname.Text & "','" & txtlname.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "','" & txtdob.Text & "','" & txttelephone.Text & "','" & txthqualifi.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "','" & txtsalary.Text & "')", myconnection)
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myconnection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: What is your actual problem? I can't see a question anywhere here in between the keyword clutter in your title.

Comment: And it's not just a small vulnerability: it's **huge, gaping, drive-an-industrial-bulldozer-through** type vulnerability, further compounded by the fact that you're committing the cardinal sin of connection as sa.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, nice catch for connecting as sa

Answer (score 5):

Well, at first glance, I can see a missing value in your query text:
I can count 9 fields and only 8 values... but this could be only an typing error.

More serious instead is the lack of parameter use. As @slaks pointed in its comment, this kind of code leads to [Sql Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also, you are passing all values as strings. I doubt that your `[staff]` table contains only text fields (DOB, DateJoinIn, AppointedAs). If it does, your schema design is horribly broken. The parameters could also help avoid this kind of error. Finally, connecting with the sa account will cause your dba to hunt you down and beat you to within an inch of your life.

Please rewrite your method in this way:

```vb
Private Sub cmdsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsave.Click 
    Using (myconnection as SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=;database=medisam"))
        myconnection.Open() 
        mycommand = New SqlCommand("insert into staff([FirstName],[LastName],[Address],[DOB], " & _
                                   "[TelephoneNum], [DateJoinIn], [HighestQualifi], [AppointedAs], [Salary]) " & _
                                   "VALUES (@first, @last, @address, @dob, @tel, @dateJ, @highQ, @appointed, @sal)", myconnection)

        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", txtfname.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", txtlname.Text) 
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob",txtdob.Text) ' if this is a date, need to convert
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel",txttelephone.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateJ", txt??? Missing ????)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@highQ",txthqualifi.Text)
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appointed",ComboBox1.SelectedValue) ' need to convert ??? 
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sal",txtsalary.Text) ' need to convert ???
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    End Using

End Sub
```